# How to decide for the contamination value (proportion of the outliers) in my dataset?

Tags: data-cleaning, outlier

I should decide on the contamination value while using the Isolation Forests algorithm (I am using the sklearn implementation). Otherwise, sklearn's default is 0.1.

I am worried if I decide for this parameter with experimenting on my current dataset, it will differ by time as I would be receiving new data points very soon.

How can I know that this parameter better than any other, just by experimenting it with outlier removal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so probably this was obvious but here is what I did. 
I used the

> `scores = decision_function(x)`

instead of just predicting the anomalies, and obtained the anomaly scores for each instance. Afterwards, I could draw the anomaly distribution of the dataset and set a better outlier proportion regarding the distribution.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on this answer a bit more? What does the `decision_function` give you and how do you translate it to a firm value like `0.1`?

Comment: @mari Thanks for your great answer. May I ask you kindly to have a look at related post [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/90720/incorrect-results-of-isolationforest)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to experiment something like that I think you can add some outliers into your data for that respective field and see what are its effects.

If you find that these are prone to outliers(most of of the features are), then you can handle situation by removing such outliers before appending to the existing data.

What is your target variable?
Did you do any kind of Correlation analysis/ Predictor Importance?

Comment: Adding outliers is rather complicated in my case since I have 130 dimensions and my aim is to detect the outliers that I could not detect with just a general analysis on the obvious attributes. I have a regression problem and my target variable is continues values with a wide range (I use gradient boosting regression trees). I applied some correlation analysis for feature reduction but I am not sure if this is what you meant.

Comment: The reason why I suggested that was to see if they are prone to outliers or not. Do you know the target variable?

Comment: Yes, I know the target variable but don't know nor visualize the outliers.

Comment: Apply Boruta package, give the target variable and it will give you predictor importance and it will tell you the important features.

Comment: @mari use cluster analysis to find out the outliers

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. However, I have 130 dimensions and not sure how could I be able to visualize the clusters. I applied a subspace selection method to find the features that are the correlated the most. Now I will try giving these subspaces to the Isolation Forest. But I am still not sure how to select the outlier proportion other than evaluating on this parameter.

Comment: I would suggest you predictor importance test and then do cluster analysis on the important variables